# Bottom button not showing in iOS Simulator

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad, xib

I am developing an app for iOS in which i took new `ViewController`

In that `ViewController` i dragged two `UIButtons`

Here is the image of `.xib` file 
[image]:
but when i run this project in my simulator i am unable to see my bottom button, you can see here in my simulator,
[image]:
Where i am doing mistake ? i am not using `autolayout` because my deployment target is **iOS 4.3**

***Thanks in advance.***

Comment: I guess your button is hidden by tabs.

Comment: @krunal your button below the tabbar.

Comment: Place your button above the tab bar.

Comment: from screenshot in xib file click on view and then on right side window choose bottom bar as tabbar then it will give you perfect layout to set and then you can set your button from xib with exact idea

Comment: I have created tabBar programmatically in my `appDelegate`

Comment: @eptdeveloper: when i select bottom as TabBar it shows http://i.imgur.com/qMhaRxF.png

Comment: okay got the problem it's because of navigationbar where the space for Go Social comes from?? so you also need to set topbar as navigationbar same way you set bottom bar it will help you in proper management

Comment: @eptdeveloper: problem solved, mark your comment as answer :) i wil accept that still i didn't got the answer properly why i need to choose top bar as navigation bar, and bottom as Tabbar. The `.xib` which i have created that is without navigation and Tabar which is nothing but part between Navigation and Tabbar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if we create the navigationbar and tabbar programmatically then occupies a space in our viewcontroller so if we need to set our viewcontroller from .xib properly then we must have to left the space of navigation and tabbar by selectin those from .xib so that we can have exact space left for our other stuff i'm glad that it helped you. you're welcome. :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your trouble caused by tab bar, that you create from code. I assume, you will see your button in case of simple comment line with tab bar creation. As this button is hidden, you can change it's y position or change size of your view in xib file.

Answer (score 0):

I have observed such problems when we are using different sizes of .xib and iPhone simulator 
i mean to say if u are using Ratina 4 for .xib .. make sure that u r also using iPhone simulator of Ratina 4 and the frame of TabBar Controller should b (0,0,320,568)

And in the case of Ratina 3.5 it should be (0,0,320,480)

Comment: can u tell me which ratina are using for nib file ??

Comment: are you adding your button programmatically?? if yes then please change its Y coordinate...